# Añadir "%" al final de cadena formateada

Tags: python, django, string, formato

Estoy calculando el porcentaje y necesito que en la cadena quede el simbolo %

```
def porcentaje(divisor, numerador):
    return '%s%' % (round(float(divisor) / float(numerador) * 100, 2))
```

Esta es la función que estoy usando, pero me genera un error de

> incomplete format

Como puedo solucionar esto.

Gracias a todos de antemano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El error es obviamente porque entiende que el segundo `%` es una marca de reemplazo a la hora de formatear la cadena. Debes escapar dicho carácter, para ello solo antepón otro `%` delante:

```
def porcentaje(divisor, numerador):
    return '%s%%' % (round(float(divisor) / float(numerador) * 100, 2))
```

ten en cuenta que puedes usar el propio formateo para redondear:

```
def porcentaje(divisor, numerador):
    return "%.2f%%" % (divisor / numerador * 100)
    # return "%.2f%%" % (float(divisor) / numerador * 100) # Python 2
```

No obstante, si usas Python >= 3.6 te recomiendo usar literales de cadena formateados y no el viejo formateo mediante `%`, es más legible y más eficiente incluso:

```
def porcentaje(divisor, numerador):
    return f'{divisor / numerador:.2%}'
```

`format()` /`str.format` también es otra posibilidad que funciona también en versiones previas de Python 3 y Python 2.7. Tiene un pequeño handicap en rendimiento con respecto a los anteriores por la llamada al método, aunque también es el más flexible:

```
def porcentaje(divisor, numerador):
    return format(divisor / numerador, ".2%")
    # return format(float(divisor) / numerador, ".2%") # Python 2
```

en este caso el builtin `format` es mejor opción por eficiencia que `str.format`, aunque se puede obviamente usar también:

```
def porcentaje(divisor, numerador):
     return "{:.2%}".format(divisor / numerador)
    # return "{:.2%}".format(float(divisor) / numerador) # Python 2
```

Los especificadores de formato usados son:

- `.2f` trata el valor numérico como float y redondea a dos decimales.
- `.2%` por su parte  multiplica el valor por 100, redondea a dos decimales y muestra el símbolo `%` al final.

Para más información sobre las posibilidades que ofrecen f-string y `format` te recomeindo mirarte  [Format specification minilanguage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Excelente información, muchas gracias he solucionado mi problema.